# Unable to add a new column with foreign key

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel when adding a new column to the existing table I am getting the above error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`schoolmanagement`.`#sql-314_2c`, CONSTRAINT
>   `students_parentsid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parentsid`) REFERENCES
>   `parent_names` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `students`
>   add constraint `students_parentsid_foreign` foreign key (`parentsid`)
>   references `parent_names` (`id`) on delete cascade)

at

```
    public function up(){
        Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parentsid')->after('id');
            $table->foreign('parentsid')->references('id')->on('parent_names')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
```

just need to insert a column for the existing table  with foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're trying to create a new column with a foreign key constraint but without setting a default value. So you either set it to be `nullable` or set a default value (which must be an existed ID in your `parent_names` table)

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parentsid')->default(1);
```

Comment: Or you can add the column with no constraint, then update your data so the constraint will be satisfied for all your records when you add it.